# body onload and google maps conflict

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a google map and a javascript function that I want to trigger as soon as the page loads, but there is a conflict with two scripts. How can I workaround this problem?

Here is the jsfiddle page for my work.
http://jsfiddle.net/xhN7V/4/

Comment: What was the conflict? And which line of code is throwing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a duplicate "id" attribute on your main div (it has both "submitform" and "form" ids). Remove one and it works for me. When you have weird problems, your first step should always be to [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what's conflicting and how much control of when the scripts load, you might be able to do something like:

```
    GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(function() {  
        OnLoad();  
        show('form');      
    });
```

Comment: it did not work, can you create a jsfiddle if possible? May be I am doing something wrong?